# Thresholding a Two dimensional array in python

Tags: python, arrays, threshold

am trying to achieve a min-max threshold on a two-dimensional array it takes some time that I might need in further processes anyone has a better idea how to do it

```
def thresholding(arr,rows,cols,max,min):
    for x in range(arr.shape[0]):
        for y in range(arr.shape[1]):
            for i in range(rows):
                for j in range(cols):
                    if(arr[x,y,i,j] >= max):
                        arr[x,y,i,j] = max
                    elif(arr[x,y,i,j] <= min):
                        arr[x,y,i,j] = min
    return arr
```

Comment: Can you show an example of what your array looks like? Why does a 2d array have 4 indices? Are `rows == arr.shape[0]` and `cols == arr.shape[1]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`numpy.clip`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html):

```
np.clip(np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]), 2, 4)   # [[2,2,3], [4,4,4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited your code

```py
def thresholding(arr,max_,min_):
    '''
    input
    ------
    arr : 2d array
    max_ : Intended max value for threshold
    min_ : Intended min value for threshold
    
    Notes
    ------
    Takes an array with the elements of a, 
    and returns an array where values < min are replaced with min(provided), 
    and those > max with max(provided)
    '''

    for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
      for j in range(arr.shape[1]):
        if arr[i,j] > max_:
          arr[i,j] = max_
        if arr[i,j] < min_:
          arr[i,j] = min_
    return arr
```

you can also use np.clip and it has a lot more functionalities.refer here.
[np.clip](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html)